# multiple mice having the same problems on one computer but not on others

Tags: usb, windows-10, mouse

so first things first i have a windows computer that i can't make any hardware changes to and with every mouse that i plug into the ports it messes up with either the left/right click either swapping or double tapping at random times or the scroll wheel basically ignoring my command and doing whatever it wants. what's odd is that these mice don't do this on any other computers and they only show one problem no matter how many times i swap them out. i think it's the usb ports and if it's that i am basically done. i am hoping its a software problem interpreting the signals wrong as the keyboard usb drives and all other devices seem fine. but i don't know all that much so here i am, any help?

Comment: Does it have a PS2 connection, if so, get a USB to PS2 converter.  Otherwise try a different USB port.  It sounds like you need to either add a PCI-E USB card and solve this problem that way or do a full on hardware replacement

Comment: they are all usb mice and keyboards. it does not have a ps2 port and all of the ports do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Plug a mouse into the computer.

hold windows+X

Navigate to "Device Manager" with the arrow keys. (As to avoid any mouse problems)

A window will pop up.

Hit Tab once. (Your computer name should be highlighted)

There may or may not be a key on the keyboard called the "apps key" It looks like a box with a few horizontal lines on it, typically it's close to right ctrl. Hit that if you have it. If don't you'll have to try and navigate your cursor to you computer name and right click.

With your arrow keys navigate to "Scan for hardware changes" and hit enter.

Give it a minute or even a restart.

Hopefully that solves the problem.

Comment: The hardware is detected that isn't the problem.  The hardware is just malfunctioning.

Comment: I was thinking there may be something wrong with the drivers for the mice, hoping the hardware scan would reinstall new drivers.

Comment: i've tried that and now it's not just mice it's keyboards and hard drives/pen drives too they get corrupted files after moving them. i thing the drives are broken